# Limiting number of users accessing asp.net website

Tags: asp.net

What is the best way to limit the number of (concurrent) users accessing a web application that any one can introduce for selling website/application to client and how to increase the number of users accessing it remotely?

Comment: I think you need to work on explaining what you're after a bit more.  You are probably looking at the number of concurrent users.  It is not clear whether you are going to be establishing 'sessions' across separate interactions with the web app.  [...more...]

Comment: Also, separate the 'how to increase' part of the question into a separate sentence.  I think that is probably asking "how can I administratively alter the permitted number of sessions".  That's easy; edit the data in the database that says how many concurrent sessions. [...more...]

Comment: However, you probably also have in mind not allowing that to happen except by the publisher of the application authorizing it - probably on receipt of more money from the people deploying the application.  In that case, you're dealing with licencing and licence enforcement. [...more...]

Comment: So, you need to expand on your question to make it clear what you are really asking about.  (I'd expect that the limit can be provided by data encrypted with a private key - you embed the public key into the application, and use that to decrypt the encrypted data that specifies the limits.)

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/728812/limit-number-of-users-accessing-a-web-asp-net-application

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use the in-process session state management, you can use the [HttpApplicationState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplicationstate.aspx) class, by introducing the Global.asax file and putting something like this in the code behind:

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Application["ActiveSessions"] = 0;
}

void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        Application.Lock();

        int activeSessions = (int) Application["ActiveSessions"] + 1;
        int allowedSessions = 10; // retrieve the threshold here instead

        Application["ActiveSessions"] = activeSessions;

        if (activeSessions > allowedSessions)
            System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("~/UserLimitReached.aspx", false);
    }
    finally
    {
        Application.UnLock();
    }
}

void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Application.Lock();
    Application["ActiveSessions"] = (int)Application["ActiveSessions"] - 1;
    Application.UnLock();
}
```

Then, in the UserLimitReached.aspx you would call HttpSession.Abandon() to effectively terminate the current session so it does not count towards the limit. You'll have to figure out the rest yourself. :)

Comment: Remember that Session_End will not be invoked if your session is stored in registry or SqlServer. Check the comments when you create a new global.asax file that make this clear.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to track active sessions in a database, and each time a user logs in, check the number of active sessions. If it is below a threshold, let them in, if not, bounce them.

To administer this number remotely, a simple admin form that lets you update the threshold in the database is simple enough.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the previous answers, I think you will need to introduce your own timeout so that sessions aren't left lingering and locked. Rather than use sessions, if you have a login, you can monitor it based on logins and keep them active by recording the most recent activity per user in a dictionary/array. That should make it easy to see which users are using the site, and which are the n most recently active users. If you tie that with the sessions, you could expire sessions used by the least recently active user. The effect of this is that if more than the specified number of users try use the website, some (the least active) will continually need to login. Given the disconnected nature of web apps, I think you may have to allow a certain % of grace so that when limited to 20 users, you actually allow maybe 22 to be concurrently active.

Comment: what did you mean by session "left lingering" or "locked" ? Is it possible to reproduce this ? I have made some tests and Session_End() seems to be always called, even if user close browser or the session expires by itself.

Comment: @tigrou If the user closes their browser and starts again, their previous session will not have ended, and the count of active sessions will increment for their new session. I think ASP will (after 20 mins by default) end the inactive sessions, but it could lead to a denial of service because what you think are "active" sessions are no longer active but are restricting users due to `Application["ActiveSessions"]` being at it's limit.