# Limit number of users accessing a java web application

Tags: java, web-applications

My problem same as [Limit number of users accessing a web ASP .NET application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728812/limit-number-of-users-accessing-a-web-asp-net-application) but i m looking a solution in java6 tomcat7 and struts 2
Requirement:

1. only N user can login at a time.
2. same user can not login from another system / browser.
3. if N+1  user try to login then display message and reject.
4. How to handle if user will not log out properly (close the browser / session timeout / network issue / etc..)

i m thinking use a static map and makes an entry for login and logout.
Could you please provide any suggestion/idea ?
Thanks
-Jiggi

Answer (score 3):

You can count number of active sessions using the code below

```
public class SessionCounter implements HttpSessionListener {  

     private static int activeSessions = 0;  

    public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent se) {  
        activeSessions++;  
    }  

     public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent se) {  
        if(activeSessions > 0)  
            activeSessions--;  
    }  


     public static int getActiveSessions() {  
        return activeSessions;  
     }  
 }
```

This way you can limit the sessions. Ex: if active session are 20, don't create any more

Answer (score 1):

You will probably want to keep the state of users in a table.

1) select count(*) from users where state=1 --assuming 1 is loggedin

2) select state from users where name=?

3) if sql in 1 returns too many, just reject the login

4) timeouts. I'm afraid it is the only thing that works in a stateless web world. If the user does not check in for 30 minutes (or whatever the timeout), set him to logged out. Any action by the user should constitute a "check in"

Instead of a simple state indicator, you could also keep a date of "last activity" which can work as an automatic timeout if no activity has been recorded for a while.