# ConCurrent Users Limit for iis7 application asp.net 2.0

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

what is the concurrent request for IIS7 Hosted ASP.NET 2.0 Application?

and can we change the concurrent request by using or defing in web.config?

Comment: http://blogs.x2line.com/al/archive/2010/01/04/3718.aspx

Comment: Please look following link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/380167/limiting-number-of-users-accessing-asp-net-website You can get your answer from there, let me know if you don't!

Comment: When i add this tag in web.config as mentioned
<system.web>
    <applicationPool maxConcurrentRequestsPerCPU="12" maxConcurrentThreadsPerCPU="0" requestQueueLimit="5000" />
</system.web>

Configuration Error
Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: Unrecognized configuration section system.web/applicationPool.

Source Error:
Line 25:   </appSettings>
Line 26:   <system.web>
Line 27:     <applicationPool

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the **ASP.NET Tuning** section:

[Chapter 17 — Tuning .NET Application Performance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647813.aspx)