# Only one user of asp.net web application at time

Tags: asp.net, concurrency, global-asax

I have a specific request to allow only one user to use asp.net application at time because of web application nature.

I've tried to implement this by using Application state using some sort of session counter which is incrementing on session_start and decrementing on session_end, but the problem is that session starts immediately when application display login form (because of form authentication).

If first user browser displays login.aspx, session_start in global.asax is called and sessioncounter is increased for 1. SessionCounter now equals 1.

If another user browser also displays login.aspx, before first user is authenticated, session_start in global.asax is called and sessioncounter is increased for 1. SessionCounter now equals 2.

My idea was to authenticate user only if SessionCounter <= 1. But in upper described case we will have a lock becase sessionCounter is already 2 and if first or second user tries to login, it will not be able to authenticate because sessioncounter is greater then 1.

The second problem is when session times out before authentication times out. If first user's session times out, and in that moment second user tries to login second user will succeed to enter application. But what happens if first users makes some postback because his auhentication has not timed out. New session will be started, session_Start event handler will be called, session counter will increase, but user will still be logged on because user is already authenticated.

What is the best approach? Is it possible to avoid Application state because ASP.net 3.5 has known issue of calling session_end immediately after session_Start if session object is not used.

I've thought about using some database flag, but then I'll have another problem. What happens if user closes browser before resetting this flag. I can insert some timestamp when raising flag. Then I'll have following scenario:

First user logs in. DB flag is raised and timestamp is inserted. First user forgets to log out and only closes browser.

Second user tries to log in. DB flag is checked and because it is already raised he can not access application. If I set one more condition to check if some period of time has passed from last inserted timestamp, for example 30 min, I could allow second user to access application regardless of DB flag, but that is not good solution becase I'll have to wait for this period of time.

What is the best solution for this problem? Is there any global variable available in .net framework which allows us to check total online user count (I am not using membership provider)?

Comment: Did you try the method here?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/380167/limiting-number-of-users-accessing-asp-net-website

Comment: Thanks. It worked. I didn't know i can response.redirect from session_start.

Comment: There is a good trick to solve this issue... I am writing sysdate and username every 5s to application state with ajax.. If some other user tries to access this page I am checking if some period of time (for example 5 minute) has passed from last date written in app state.. If someone accidentlly closes browser, javascript would stop writing sysdate to application state and next user will have to wait some period of time to access this page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to do this through IIS by limiting the number of connections and adding a custom error page to handle `403.9 (Forbidden - Too Many Users)` errors.

[Limiting Connections to Manage Resources (IIS 6.0)](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/e0d3b1db-cb0f-4c12-a3fc-584784ef23b5.mspx?mfr=true)

[image]

Comment: This is good solution, but I can't use it because I have to share IIS web site with some other apps, and setting Connections limited to 1 will cause other applications to have limited connections.

Comment: You can limit connections per application.